# How do I copy images I have in a .txt file from one folder to another

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder that contains 20,000 images. I only want 139 of these images copied into another folder. The list of images I want to be copied over is in a .txt file on my desktop.

This is my second day trying this and I am completely lost.

Can anyone show me a code that will do this for me?

Comment: Where is the code that you have tried to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import shutil

folder_with_images_path = Path("path_to_the_folder_with_images") # Change the string to the actual path to the folder with the images.
folder_to_copy_to_path = Path("path_to_folder_to_copy_to") # Change the string to the actual path to the folder to copy the images to.
file_with_names_path = Path("path_to_the_file") # Change the string to the actual path to the .txt file.

with open(file_with_names_path) as txt_file:
    images_to_copy_list = txt_file.read().split('\n')

for image in os.listdir(folder_with_images_path):
    if image in images_to_copy_list:
        shutil.move(folder_with_images_path / image, folder_to_copy_to_path / image)
```

I tried it and it worked very well for me. Please let me know if it helps you.

Comment: It worked!! you are an actual genius mate lol. Thank you very much. P.s i tried to copy the code i already had and paste it as an answer but it kept giving me errors and i didnt know how to properly add it to the comment so very sorry for not showing my work

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import shutil
import glob
```

##Defining the path

```
txt_file_path =  'Path/for/image.txt'
save_path = 'Path/for/save_folder'
src_dir = 'Path/for/JPEGImages/directory'
```

### Creating save image folder for storing the images

```
if not os.path.exists(save_path):
    os.makedirs(save_path)

images_txt = [] ### store the image name
```

##Text file read and store the filename in above list

```
with open(txt_file_path) as f_input:
        for file in f_input:
            file = file.strip()
            file = os.path.split(file)[1]
            images_txt.append(file)
```

### copying the images from source directory to the save folder and add jpg if images txt file have only image name no extension.

```
for image_name in images_txt:
    img_directory = os.path.join(src_dir, image_name + '.jpg') 
    shutil.copy(img_directory,save_path)
    print("img_directory",img_directory)
```